# When using PayPal API is it possible to get payer info?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Currently we use IPN, and when we receive notification there is payer info, such as email, residence_country, first_name, last_name.

We want to switch to API (because it is possible to create refund thought API). But in API calls create payment and execute payment,  there is no information about payer.

How can I get this payer info?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the REST APIs you need to use [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/) instead of IPN.

That webhook data will include the info you're looking for.

IPN is used for PayPal Standard and Classic (NVP/SOAP) APIs.

Comment: I checked webhooks in webook simulator, as far as I can see there no such information.